# How can I assign an object a value from a list? Unity 3D C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to assign a state (Cold, Burnt, Nothing) to an object (9 objects to be specific). But I'm trying to make it random. Meaning I want a random state from a list to be assigned to a random object (chosen from a list). I also don't care if some buildings have the same state as long as not all of them have the same one. The way I went about doing this is like like this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<GameObject> Buildings = new List<GameObject>(9);

    public List<string> States = new List<string>();
}
```

that's how far I got. I'm probably doing it the wrong way, and there's a better way of doing it. That's why I came to stack overflow for some help. If you need other information please let me know. Thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply go through all your buildings and for each one pick a random entry from the states.

Then you wouldn't use a `GameObject` but rather have a dedicated class like e.g.

```
public class Building : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string state;
}
```

on all your building objects and in your manager rather

```
public List<Building> Buildings;
```

and then do e.g.

```
foreach(var b in Buildings)
{
    b.state = States[Random.Range(0, States.Length)];
}
```

---

However, in general you should avoid doing stuff based on `strings`. I would rather use an `enum` like e.g.

```
public enum State
{
    None,
    Cold,
    Burnt,
    ...
}

public class Building : MonoBehaviour
{
    public State state;
}
```

And then rather use e.g.

```
var states = Enum.GetValues<State>();
foreach(var b in Buildings)
{
    b.state = (State) states[UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, states.Length)];
}
```